# Properties.Settings.Default.Default.Save() does not work

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created code in WPF to let the window remember its last location like this:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Rect storedLoc = Properties.Settings.Default.WindowSavedLocation;
        this.Top = storedLoc.Top;
        this.Left = storedLoc.Left;
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("No settings stored !");
    }
}

private void Window_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.WindowSavedLocation = RestoreBounds;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

When I build the application I can see that the app.exe.config file has the setting

```
WindowSavedLocation
```

but it just does not save and throws no exception.

Everytime I run the application, it says "No settings stored !".

It's scope is user.

Comment: Have you confirmed that you're actually able to save the value? Does another setting of another type (say string, or integer) save?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I repro.  The Remarks section of the Window.RestoreBounds property docs is relevant to your problem:

> If you query RestoreBounds before the
>   window has been shown or after it has
>   been closed, Empty is returned.

Use the Closing event instead so the RestoreBounds property is still valid.

Comment: Hans, your answer solved my problem. The app. level config. file is saved in the same folder as the exe.Where is the user level file is saved?

Comment: Don't hesitate to start a new question.